# Matrix concatenation error

Tags: matlab

```
 trainingSet = imageSet(imgFolder1, 'recursive');

 % Using HOG Features

 cellSize = [4 4];
 hogFeatureSize = length(hog_4x4);

 %% Train a Digit Classifier

 trainingFeatures = [];
 trainingLabels   = [];

 for digit = 1:numel(trainingSet)

 numImages = trainingSet(digit).Count;           
features  = zeros(numImages, hogFeatureSize, 'single');

for i = 1:numImages

    img = read(trainingSet(digit), i);

    % Apply pre-processing steps
    lvl = graythresh(img);
    img = im2bw(img, lvl);        

    features(i, :) = extractHOGFeatures(img, 'CellSize', cellSize);
end
```

Please I need help, when I run this code above I get errors at # features(i, :) which says ( Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch).

I am actually trying to extract HOG features from about 20images, and I discovered that they have varying number of images being extracted. How do I solve this problem please. Thank you.

Comment: Put a comma instead of a colon after `img`, i.e. `extractHOGFeatures(img,` ...

Comment: Thank you CST-Link. I have done so. Still giving the error

Comment: Turn `features` into a cell array: `features = cell(numImages, 1);` then assign the extracted features like this: `features{i} = extractHOGFeatures(img, 'CellSize', cellSize);` Side note: you still didn't corrected the colon in your post...

Comment: Thank you CST-Link. It worked. I appreciate sir